# How to convert date in format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" to UNIX timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I convert a time in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" (e.g. `"2011-07-15 13:18:52"`) to a UNIX timestamp?

I tried this piece of Javascript code:

```
date = new Date("2011-07-15").getTime() / 1000
alert(date)
```

And it works, but it results in `NaN` when I add time('2011-07-15 13:18:52') to the input.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the long date constructor and specify all date/time components:

```
var match = '2011-07-15 13:18:52'.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/)
var date = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6])
// ------------------------------------^^^
// month must be between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: dude am getting the timestamp but its not the correct one am getting. when I give '2011-07-15 14:54:12' I get the timestamp as '1313434452'. But when I check this using 'http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm' its shows the timestamp converted date to Mon, 15 Aug 2011 07:48:52 GMT which is wrong.

Answer (score 15):

Following code will work for format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`:

```
function parse(dateAsString) {
    return new Date(dateAsString.replace(/-/g, '/'))
}
```

This code converts `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` to `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss` that is easily parsed by `Date` constructor.

Comment: This answer is the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You've accepted an answer, but a much simpler regular expression can be used:

```
function stringToDate(s)  {
  s = s.split(/[-: ]/);
  return new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
}

alert(stringToDate('2011-7-15 20:46:3'));
```

Of course the input string must be the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Months start from 0, unlike the days! So this will work perfectly ([tested](http://jsfiddle.net/FLmkX/))

```
function dateToUnix(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) {
    return ((new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second))).getTime() / 1000.0);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This returns number of milliseconds since Jan. 1st 1970:
`Date.parse('2011-07-15 10:05:20')`

Just divide by 1000 to get seconds instead of milliseconds..

Comment: date = new Date.parse('2011-07-15 10:05:20')/ 100  is this what you ment... I am getting error NaN

Comment: `console.log(Date.parse('2011-07-15 10:05:20'));` is `NaN`, [this is not a recognised input format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: Must vary from browser to browser, then. Tested it in Chrome, no problems (http://jsfiddle.net/nslr/v2xQ6/)